# Sklearn for Python: Is there a way to see how close a prediction was?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using this code to perform predictions to classify text:

```
predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)
```

My predictions either come out saying that the text snippet belongs to subject A or subject B. However, I want to do further analysis on predictions that are shaky -- that is, if the model was really unsure whether it was A or B, but had to pick one for the sake of it. Is there a way to extract the relative confidence of the predictions?

Code:

`X_train` has `["Sentence I know belongs to Subject A", "Another sentence that describes Subject A", "A sentence about Subject B", "Another sentence about Subject B"...]`, etc

`Y_train` contains the corresponding classifiers: `["Subject A", "Subject A", "Subject B", "Subject B", ...]`, etc.

`predict_these_X` is a list of sentences I wish to classify: `["Some random sentence", "Another sentence", "Another sentence again", ...]` etc.

```
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

    X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(predict_these_X)
    X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)

    estimator = BernoulliNB()
    estimator.fit(X_train_tfidf, Y_train)
    predictions = estimator.predict(X_new_tfidf)

    print estimator.predict_proba(X_new_tfidf)
    return predictions
```

result:

```
[[  9.97388646e-07   9.99999003e-01]
 [  9.99996892e-01   3.10826824e-06]
 [  9.40063326e-01   5.99366742e-02]
 [  9.99999964e-01   3.59816546e-08]
 ...
 [  1.95070084e-10   1.00000000e+00]
 [  3.21721965e-15   1.00000000e+00]
 [  1.00000000e+00   3.89012777e-10]]
```

Comment: That depends on what model you are using?

Comment: @ShantanuDeshpande MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB

# generate some artificial data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=50, weights=[0.1, 0.9])


# your estimator
estimator = BernoulliNB()
estimator.fit(X, y)

# generate predictions
estimator.predict(X)
Out[164]: array([1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1])

# to get confidence on the prediction
estimator.predict_proba(X)

Out[163]: 
array([[ 0.0043,  0.9957],
       [ 0.0046,  0.9954],
       [ 0.0071,  0.9929],
       ..., 
       [ 0.8392,  0.1608],
       [ 0.0018,  0.9982],
       [ 0.0339,  0.9661]])
```

Now you see, for each of the first 3 observations, it has over 99% probability to be the positive case.

Comment: What does make_classification return? How would I combine the last few steps with the pieces I already have? Do you feed it raw data or transformed data from the vectors etc?

Comment: just generate some artificial data. You can replace this part with your own real data.

Comment: Hm I just tried this and it's saying all the numbers are near-0 which I know is not the case

Comment: All close-to-zero number means the algorithm classify it as negative case `y = 0`. Is your y-labels balanced?

Comment: Also you're comparing X (the data you fit) to X, the data you used for the learning. Isn't that considered self-feedback?

Comment: I don't know what "balanced" means here, I have one label = "Subject A" and another "Subject B"

Comment: This is over-simplified case to demonstrate how to get confidence on prediction. Of course, you can use cross-validation utility to train and the predict on test dataset.

Comment: can you upload your data file? I can show you how to process it using sklearn.

Comment: 'balanced' refers to the proportion of your y-labels. Are they 50%-50%? or one case is extremely less frequent when compared to other, i.e. 5%-95% (like the case in credit fraud)?

Comment: I added code to the OP to show you what I am currently doing. My data file is quite large and I cannot post it here. I added descriptors to show what each of my lists holds.

Comment: It's about 40% to 60% y-label composition across both categories

Comment: what's the result of `predict_proba()`

Comment: Posted results from predict_proba

Comment: Oh, I am being silly. I was assuming the exponents were telling me everything was near-zero. Some of these are near 1, others are 0. Nice!

Comment: Congratulations! It seems your algo works pretty well in out-of-sample testing.